GeoServer HTML Filter Chain not working
Following a listserv message at https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/37864885/ I've gone into Geoserver and created a a new HTML Filter Chain "webPreview" with path (ANT pattern) "/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage"
I checked "Allow creation of an HTTP session for storing the authentication token" (as the list serv and I don't know whether that's really required.  I also added Chain filters "rememberme" and "form" in that order to follow instructions.
Now, on my local setup, the Available side has anon and basic, while the Selected has rememberme and form in that order for both.
Going back to "Filter chain testing" on Authentication I type in "/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage" and get the new webPreview as I moved it to the top.
However, even after restarting GeoServer, an anon user can go to my Layer Preview page and see all the layers.  I'd like to prevent this and Demos and some other bookmarkable stuff to the anon users.

I followed the instructions in the documentation and it works on initial load of the Layer Preview page, and redirects to login, but if I click the "Layer Preview" a second time it takes me to the Layer Preview.
Is that expected or is there any way to have it always block Layer Preview?
Here's my admin screen setup: 

Check the documentation rather than an email list. If it is broken nobody has told us yet.
The use of a Filter chain to restrict access to MapPreviewPage was a very creative solution to accomplish this goal without making a change to the software. Since this is not a feature of the software it is not covered by test-coverage as part of each release.

I have also tested this and found that it seems to work on a physical install of GeoServer.  I have found that it doesn't work using the Docker image.  I even copied the geoserver_data folder from a working instance to the Docker and it didn't work.
Are you using Docker or is this a real installation?
